# Issue when scrolling with fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a carousel slider which will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0vKP.png), similar what we have in android.

I am at the very beginning of its creation, and the issue which I am stuck on is that I am using `position: fixed;`, but I only want it to be fixed horizontally, because it will need to be scrolled.

How do I only apply `position: fixed;` to the horizontal scroll?

Bellow, is the code I am currently using:

```js
var val = 0;
$("button").click(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    $('.MySlide:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').removeClass('MySlide' + (((val + i) % 9) + 1) + '');
    $('.MySlide:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').addClass('MySlide' + (((val + i + 1) % 9) + 1) + '');
  }
  val = (val + 1) % 9;
});
```

```css
.long-div {
  height: 300px;
}
.MySlides-wrap {
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 350px;
}
.MySlide {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  transition: transform 500ms;
  left: -75px;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: blue;
}
.MySlide1 {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(0.6, 0.6);
}
.MySlide2 {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(150px, 0px) scale(0.7, 0.7);
}
.MySlide3 {
  z-index: 3;
  transform: translate(300px, 0px) scale(0.8, 0.8);
}
.MySlide4 {
  z-index: 4;
  transform: translate(450px, 0px) scale(0.9, .9);
}
.MySlide5 {
  z-index: 5;
  transform: translate(600px, 0px) scale(1, 1);
}
.MySlide6 {
  z-index: 4;
  transform: translate(750px, 0px) scale(0.9, .9);
}
.MySlide7 {
  z-index: 3;
  transform: translate(900px, 0px) scale(0.8, 0.8);
}
.MySlide8 {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(1050px, 0px) scale(0.7, 0.7);
}
.MySlide9 {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translate(1200px, 0px) scale(0.6, 0.6);
}
.MySlideFutured {
  z-index: 9;
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>teste slider</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="long-div"></div>
    <div class="MySlides-wrap">
      <div class="card MySlide MySlide1"></div>
      <div class="card MySlide MySlide2"></div>
      <div class="card MySlide MySlide3"></div>
      <div class="card MySlide MySlide4"></div>
      <div class="card MySlide MySlide5"></div>
      <div class="card MySlide MySlide6"></div>
      <div class="card MySlide MySlide7"></div>
      <div class="card MySlide MySlide8"></div>
      <div class="card MySlide MySlide9"></div>
    </div>
    <button>Next</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I couldn't find any which is the way I want, plus it is a good exercise for me :)

Comment: @humble.rumble everything you have said  so far is discouraging! If I am using the wrong approach, suggest e better on instead of criticize mine!

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this problem, but fixed positioning is used to stick something on a position on the screen, not a position in the webpage. I suggest creating scrollable container and control the scroll offset with jquery.

Working example (in Chrome and Firefox at least, haven't tested others):

https://jsfiddle.net/7duatxmv/

Forgive the inline styles for demonstration:

```
<div id="slideContainer" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; white-space: nowrap;">
    <div class="slide" style="display:inline-block;">
        Content 1
    </div>
    <div class="slide selected" style="display:inline-block;">
        Content 2 (scroll to me by default)
    </div>
    <div class="slide" style="display:inline-block;">
        Content 3
    </div>
</div>
```

In this scenario, the "slideContainer" would have a width equal to the width of a single slide, and you utilize the browser's native scrolling to switch between slides.

jQuery can control the scrolling via .scrollLeft() and .offset().